# Inheriting Doctrine Models to keep autogenerated code separated from custom code: good idea?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been doing a few Symfony2 projects lately, using doctrine as the ORM.

One thing that's been bothering me a little bit is the mix in Entities between autogenerated code / boilerplate code (field definitions, getters, setters, mappings) and business logic.

You end up with ~600 lines of code entity files of which only maybe 10% is business logic (although of course a lot of the business logic will be in the Repository classes usually, but still).

I'm considering splitting up code to keep business logic in a separate class that would extend the Entity, for more clarity, like having an Entity folder with the boilerplate code and a BusinessEntity folder with the real code.

1) Do you consider this a good design pattern?
2) Could it be accomplished without too much trouble?

Answer (score 1):

We have extended the EntityGenerator to generate traits instead of classes. Every entity is generated as a class and simply imports the trait which contains all the boilerplate code. This approach has several advantages.

- You can still generate the entities and leave the custom business logic untouched
- All the generated code is cleanly seperated from your custom code.
- You can still extend from another entity in case you are using table inheritance or extending some base entity.

Trait are only supported from PHP >= 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong saying that you could use entity repositories for your business logic?
http://www.masnun.com/2012/11/12/symfony2-doctrine-custom-entity-repositories.html